# Mysql column as week number

Tags: php, mysql

I want a table (scorecard) like this:

```
|ID  |Name  |34  |35  |36  |...
|1   |Paul  |0   |0   |0   |...
...
```

Where the numbers are weeks. So now we are in week 35, so I want to update column 35. I wrote:

```
$week = Date('W');
$sql = "UPDATE scorecard SET `'$week'` = 5 WHERE id = 1";
```

and next week it should be column 36 automatically.

Is it even possible? Obvious this didn't work, since I posted this thread :)

Comment: @Michel I don't understand why you say it can't be done, yet the answer you referenced does show a way to do it.

Comment: @Michel Oh, and I can't just `SET ´'$week'´ ... ` ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Read it a bit in a hurry.Simply \`$week\` should do.

Comment: Yea, I found out I could use backticks but my question was how to let the code automatically know which column to update depending on the week number :)

Comment: I think you can, but it will make few problems later on. So why you don't just name them like `week35`, and update the field...tadaa.

Comment: @DanielJensen You shouldn't be using that type of database naming convention. You should look into MySQL's built-in date (date time) features. Have  look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html and possibly a relational table.

Comment: *"how to let the code automatically know which column to update depending on the week number"* - @DanielJensen You would need to use a `WHERE` clause. As of now, you'd be updating your entire database without it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not quite sure I get it .. I want to update the column called "35" this week. And next week column "36". If I use the `WHERE` clause, it wouldn't choose the column but the line "where something", right?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Just updated the original question with the `WHERE` clause but still don't think that answers my question.

Comment: @DanielJensen Well, your `SET '$week'` in single quotes as shown in your edit just now, won't work. That would need to be done as you posted in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45959824/mysql-column-as-week-number#comment78877597_45959824) earlier. Your `WHERE id = 1` should work with the column name being ticked.

Comment: @Fred-ii- oh I think I've got it right now! The whole time I used `SET ´'$week'´ ` but I should just get rid of the quotes and just use the backticks :) Thank you!

Comment: @DanielJensen welcome. Well, your edit already "answered" your question *wink!*

Comment: A table with 52 week columns is bad database design. Normalise!

Comment: I agree with @trincot here as I did make a [mention of that earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45959824/mysql-column-as-week-number#comment78877709_45959824) and use a relational database. You could also make use of CASE but that's another ball of twine.

Comment: @trincot Thanks for the input. However I'm not using all 52 weeks, just 12 ;)

Comment: Anything more than 1 of the same is wrong. So 12 ... hmmm.

Comment: @trincot Why? Please let me know :) I want like a scorecard where the points is on. Like an Excel-sheet but more automatically :)

Comment: Why? For example: think of queries where you need to list the weeks where the corresponding value is above some threshold. Easy when you have a normalised database, a long SQL when not. Read about [normalisation](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php).

Comment: @trincot Oh I see .. Thank you - I'll look into that too :)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, thanks to @Fred-ii- :

```
$week = Date('W');
$sql = "UPDATE scorecard SET `$week` = 5 WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: You may also want to use a prepared statement, should the value come from user input. Should that be the case (later on) and you don't use a prepared statement, your database could be compromised and possibly deleted.